# ¿Por qué no me genera un bucle?

Tags: c++

Estamos viendo ciclos con `while`. Al hacer un programa sencillo que siga una sucesión de números hasta un número que el usuario deba dar, el problema es que al correrlo solo se queda en un número y finaliza el programa.

Aquí el código:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n,n1;

    cout << "\n\t Hasta que numero quieres que llegue la sucecion?: ";
    cin >> n1;

    n=1;
    while (n == n1);
    {
        n=n*2;
        cout << n <<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Mientras (`while`) que el número creado (`n`) sea igual al número ingresado por teclado (`n1`) entonces se ejecutará tu programa, sin embargo, si no colocas por teclado (`n1`) que será igual a tu número creado (`n`) entonces jamás ejecutará tu bucle; osease que si no se ingresa 1 no pasará nada. Trata cambiando tu condición a `n<=n1` o algo así, realmente no sé qué es lo que quieres lograr con tu programa.

Answer (score 2):

Siempre es bueno inicializar las variables a 0

```
int n = 0;
int n1 = 0;
```

El bucle while te pide una condición para seguir ejecutándose

```
while(condición)
{
//Proceso del while
}
```

pero en tu caso solo hay una forma que el while se ejecute y ese es si el usuario ingresa 1 en la variable n1

usa mejor un operador relacional "mayor que o menor que" (> , <) en lugar del comparativo ==

entonces tu while deberia quedar algo así

```
while(variable < variable1){
variable++; //Para que no se ejecute infinitamente
//Resto de tu while
}
```

Comment: Sería al revés. `variable < variable1`

Comment: Cierto o 'variable1 > variable'